# What are some solutions to show that an iPhone app is currently working on getting data?

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, notifications

I'm building an app right now that reaches out to a Web API and sometimes there is a little bit of a delay where currently nothing happens. What are options to show the user that the app is thinking about something? Any examples on how to implement and present a spinny wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest one is the UIActivityIndicator

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview

for showing the progress in a more elegant way you can use a heads up display,

https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

http://iosdevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-svprogresshud-heads-up-display.html

Answer (score 0):

A popular (and easy) solution for doing this is to use the [MBProgressHUD Library](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD).

Answer (score 0):

A progress bar or activity indicator depending on available state (time left calculation possible).